# Way to define id or class for options_for_select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can we define id for this rails select statement , i have tried doing in this way like

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(Contact::STATES), :id=>"state_job" %>
```

but it is not showing any id when i inspect it in the browser. Please help me out

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(Contact::STATES) %>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [select tag helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) looks for `options`, then `html_options`, you just need to make sure your id is in the right place (`html_options`) by passing something to the `options` parameter:

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(Contact::STATES), {}, {:id=>"state_job"} %>
```

Comment: Please vote him up...if you are helpful to his answer...vote up from me

Comment: how to set the default value using this context?

Comment: @RanaAlie The last argument to options_for_select is for a selected value, you might leverage this to define a default value, or depending on your context you may prefer to use the `prompt` or `include_blank` arguments of the select tag itself.

Comment: @Matt actually I have been struggling with jquery chosen-select, and I got it working with callback 
`("#selectId").val("myValue").trigger("chosen:updated")`.